# Html5 video play on ios with swipe

Tags: ios, html, swipe

You need user interaction to start play video on ios like click or key press, but why doesnt swipe work?

I have an example here, works well on Android, but not on ios:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNoBKq

```
jQuery('.over').swipe({
   swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     video[0].pause();
  },
  swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     video[0].play();
  },
});
```

Anybody done something similar and manage to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue,   I believe the issue is that Apple is disabling some controls to prevent unwanted downloading over cell networks.  If I use the same code inside a button press event, it works.  I have an alert fire on swipe as well, and that code runs, and the play works on other platforms,  so it definitely appears to be Apple disabling this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html